# Microsoft Health won't update

Tags: update, nokia-lumia-920, microsoft-band

The App Store says I have an update for Microsoft Health, but the download hangs part-way or falls back to Pending. This happens over cellular or Wi-Fi. Microsoft Health appears to be the only app affected - numerous other apps, including system apps, other Microsoft apps, and third-party apps, have successfully updated while I've had this problem. There's no error code. Problem persists across reboots.

The only way to get any movement once the update is hung or Pending seems to be to cancel it and re-start it. I'm hesitant to wipe the app and re-download it in case whatever's preventing the app from updating might also prevent it from re-installing. The app appears to function normally otherwise.

Is there a known solution for this, or do I just have to stay at an old version until I upgrade my phone?

Current Microsoft Health version: 1.3.11112.1
Phone: Nokia Lumia 920
OS Version: 8.10.14157.200
Firmware Revision: 3051.50009.1425.2001
Phone Software Release: Lumia Denim

Comment: If you go to store > downloads, does the app show there, or show any additional information?

Comment: It's in Downloads. Shows as Pending. That's it. Long press gives me a "cancel download" option. Tap gives the generic "Download pending" banner, with link to the Release Notes. Release Notes indicate that the current version it's trying to push should be 2015.1209.1916.0, and adds support for Band 2. So, at this rate, it's looking like I'll need a new phone before I can upgrade my Band.

Answer (score 2):

I will suggest you to uninstall the app and then reinstall it. This steps will mostly solve this type of problem.